# How to remove last push from main branch and push it to a new branch?

Tags: git

I just pushed some changes to my main branch.
Now I want to remove the last push from the main branch and move it to a new branch.
Is there any command for that?

Answer (score 1):

There is the git-cherry pick for this task.

#### `git cherry-pick <SHA-1>`

> Apply the change introduced by the commit(s) at the tip of the master branch and create a new commit(s) with this change.

The syntax of the `...` is a commit range. grab all commits from start (exclude) to the last one. If you want a single commit use a single SHA-1

[image]

Once you have the desired commit to the desired branch remove it with one of teh following as  described in here:

[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location/34519716#34519716)

- ***`git checkout`***
- ***`git reset`***

---

Read out the full [***`git cherry-pick`*** documentation for all the options you can use](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)